# Spring Boot & OAuth2: Getting ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:5555/oauth/token": Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth

based on this example https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth I have modified the source code adding repositories and other rest controllers.  The resource and authorization servers are running/configured in the same application.

I have added an endpoint "/api/login" (POST) with request body:

```
{"usernamme":"foo", "password":"bar"}
```

I want to get an access token for this user in the service called by the controller. This implementation looks as follows:

**Controller**

```
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> login(@RequestBody @Valid final LoginCommand credentials)
        throws LoginFailedException, UnexpectedErrorException {
    try {
        final OAuth2AccessToken token = securityService.authenticate(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    } catch (final InvalidGrantException badCredentialExeption) {
        throw new LoginFailedException(badCredentialExeption.getMessage());
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new UnexpectedErrorException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("OAuth2RestOperations")
private OAuth2RestOperations client;

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
    final ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = (ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails) client.getResource();
    resourceDetails.setUsername(username);
    resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
    return client.getAccessToken();
}
```

**Rest client config**

```
@Configuration
@Import({ OauthProperties2.class })
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Autowired
    private OauthProperties2 oauth;

    @Bean(name = "OAuth2RestOperations")
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
       return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
       final ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
       resource.setAccessTokenUri(oauth.getClient().getAccessTokenUri());
       resource.setClientId(oauth.getClient().getClientId());
       resource.setClientSecret(oauth.getClient().getClientSecret());
       resource.setGrantType(oauth.getClient().getGrantType());
       resource.setScope(oauth.getClient().getScope());
       return resource;
    }

}
```

**The Test**

```
public class SecurityApiControllerTest extends TestBase {

    @InjectMocks
    private SecurityApiController controller;

    @Test
    public void loginOK() throws Exception {
       final String credentials = FileUtils.readContent("requests/loginOK.json");
    // @formatter:off
        mvc.perform(post("/api/login")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content(credentials))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

**TestBase**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class TestBase {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    protected FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }
 }
```

When running the application, I can call the endpoint for example with POSTMAN. During the test I get a connection refused as described in question header. I have tried to figure out the reason why the test is not working. Can anybody give me a hint to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is so weird. It works since I have changed the TestBase class to:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// @WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```